# Take screenshot on a test assert error / exception

Tags: python, selenium, screenshot, pytest

I am running my ui tests with Python + pytest + selenium.
I need to do a screenshot on any test fail (any exception / assertion error etc.)

I would like to impement it in my BaseEnvironment class, which looks like this now

```
@pytest.mark.flaky(max_runs=3, min_passes=1)
class Rerun:
    pass

class BaseEnvironment(Rerun):
    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
        cls.driver = create_webdriver()

    @classmethod
    def teardown_class(cls):
        cls.driver.close()
        cls.driver.quit()
```

I found a lot of solutions with google but its really complicated or for pyrhon 2.x. I need something simple, like decorator. It must apply to all my tests.
But not something like add to setup **test_status = False**, on the end of each test **test_status = True** and check it in teardown. I would like to do it clean, if it possible. 
Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to do this too, the above answer was a good start but I ended up using something slightly different:

```
def screenshot_dec(func):
    def wrapper(selenium):
        try:
            func(selenium)
        except:
            selenium.save_screenshot("error_{0}.png".format(func.__name__))
            raise
    return wrapper

@screenshot_dec
def test_my_test(selenium):
    # test code here where selenium is my driver instance
```

This generates `error_test_mytest.png` on any exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a decorator that should take a screenshot after each exception and failed assertion which I believe is what you want.  Try something like the following?

```
 def decorator_screenshot(func):
     def wrapper(func, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
           return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
           return get_screenshot()
    return wrapper

@decorator_screenshot
def test_something():
    Assert.fail("failed test")
```

Comment: Its not working, getting this error before even test starts

============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.7.1, pytest-4.3.0, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.1
rootdir: C:\Tests\, inifile:
plugins: xdist-1.26.1, sugar-0.9.2, rerunfailures-6.0, forked-1.0.2, flaky-3.5.3
Dependencies.py:None (Dependencies.py)
Dependencies.py:11: in <module>
    class TestDependencies(BaseEnvironment):

E   TypeError: function() argument 1 must be code, not str
collected 0 items / 1 errors

Comment: I think I just had to ensure to return a function from the decorator.  Does the above edit help?

Comment: same error :( 
TypeError: function() argument 1 must be code, not str